# Find top ranking items by comparing multiple ranking lists

Tags: python, probability, ranking, rank

Problem summary: I have ranked the same items considering multiple properties and, all these properties are equally important. I would like to get the first elements by comparing all the ranking lists.

Problem usecase: I have trained several machine learning models and, tested on a same test list. The models were then ranked based on their test accuracy, the number of elements used to train them, and their accuracy variation across test lists.
I would like to find the model, that has the maximum accuracy across all the test elements, the minimum accuracy variation, and the minimum number of training materials.

```
Example: 

accuracy: [ model c, model b, model d, model a ] -> acc of c >>> acc of a
accuracy variation: [ model b, model a, model c, model d ] -> variation of b <<< variation of d
number of materials used [ model a, model b, model c, model d ] -> num of training elements for a <<< num of training elements d
```

I would like to use `rank biased overlap`, or `kendal tau` or any correlation mapping algorithm.

Comment: looking for the same in case you got it resolved

Comment: @zbeedatm yeah, i'll post the answer. thankyou for the reminder

Answer (score 0):

I used Robust rank aggragation in R to solve this.
First I made the ranks of each column
Then create a matrix containing all the ranks.

code is follows

```
glist <- list(temp$rankAcc, temp$rankVariance, temp$rankModel)
aggregateRanks(glist = glist, N = 4)
```

Reference:  `https://doi.org/10.1093/bioinformatics/btr709`

Credit : `Raivo Kolde`

Documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RobustRankAggreg/index.html